# How can I load an specific excel file using read-excel-file js?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

Here's a link: [read-excel-file](https://github.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file)

I'm trying to edit read-excel-file js wherein I can automatically load the excel file (.xlsx) into my html page. But I can't find a way to edit the javascript file! Here's some part of the script below:

`<input type="file" id="input" value=""/>`

```
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById('input')
  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
  ...
</script>
```

I want to enter the path of the file into **JS script** just like this instead of choosing a file:

`var workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.xlsx');`

**read-excel-file** code

```
    import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file/node'

// File path.
readXlsxFile('/path/to/file').then((rows) => {
  // `rows` is an array of rows
  // each row being an array of cells.
})

// Readable Stream.
readXlsxFile(fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file')).then((rows) => {
  ...
})
```

Can anyone help me achieve this? Please thank you

Comment: This will give you a pretty good idea

https://github.com/catamphetamine/read-excel-file

Comment: @HarshadShettigar I'm having a hard time following that link. I tried playing with the code and still don't get what I want so I posted this question here. :(

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```html
<script src="https://catamphetamine.github.io/read-excel-file/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <input type="file" id="file" />
  <div id="dtable"></div>
  <script>
    var input = document.getElementById('file')
    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
      readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(data) {
        document.getElementById('dtable').innerHTML = '<table border=1>' + data.map(row => '<tr>' + row.map(cell => `<td>${cell === null ? '' : cell}</td>`).join('') + '</tr>').join('') + '</table>'
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have copied and truncated the code found here -> https://catamphetamine.github.io/read-excel-file/

Comment: I already accomplish the code above. All Ineed to do now is to load the local file automatically upon opening without choosing a file